# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material-rc01: Affected Modules: app

Tags: androidx, android-studio-3.5

After adding `'com.google.android.material:material-rc01'` in place of <strike>com.android.support:design</strike> as per documentation, studio failed to detect the dependency.
Then I downgrade the version of dependency to 
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'`

and it works.
But why this problem arises? any explanation?

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib- 
    jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso core:3.2.0'
}
```

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material-rc01:
>   Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error arises due to the fact that you're not specifying a *version* for the implementation; the program needs the following:

1. The group
2. The name of the dependency to implement
3. Version of the dependency

All this is covered in more detail [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material/1.0.0-rc01)

When I got this error message, I solved it with the below line:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
```

As you can see, the line above follows the `implement 'compileGroup:name:version'` pattern from the list, which in *this* case is `1.0.0-rc01`; `-rc01` seems to be a name for the version, just like `-alpha09`.

Note as well that you are not **downgrading** as you say if you didn't specify a version previously, which is why your app couldn't build.

Comment: Nicely explained @FranK. It helps me in the future also.

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same issue. I solved it by using the following dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
```

To solve such issues you always can check if the lib you are looking for does really exists in Google's Maven repo: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Hope that help, cheers!